# Display popup on item hold in listview for x seconds?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview with different items inside it. They are stored in a database and a list etc.. On item hold for like 2 sec, i want a display popup to appear saying, "are you sure you want to delete this item" or something like that.

I currently only have this pop up to appear on "ItemSelected". How can i make so that if i hold down on an item for 2 sec, the display alert appear?

Current code so far

```
private async void ExampleListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var result = await DisplayAlert("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete this object?", "Delete", "Cancel");

}
```

Comment: generally you would use a ContextAction for a ListView deletion

Comment: may i ask for an example? haha. Looked up ContextAction but didn't find anything new than i looked for earlier posting this question ^^ @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found this great nuget package site. Amazing and worked for me really well!

http://www.mrgestures.com/

There is event as tapped, LongPressed, LongPressing etc. Use LongPressing event in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

```
<ListView x:Name="ContextDemoList" ItemSource="{Binding ListOfItems}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
         <ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
               Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
         </ViewCell.ContextActions>
         <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
             <Label Text="Delete Me" />
         </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the CodeBehind to handle the events:

```
public void OnDelete (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
    var selectedItem = mi.CommandParameter; // May need to cast this object
    vm.ListOfItems.Remove(selectedItem);
}
```

Where ListOfItems is your ObeservableCollection.